# Connection works on Visual Studio 2015 but not on 2019

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I have created an Oracle connection in Visual Studio 2015 and it works but the same details do no work in Visual Studio 2019. Do we need to change anything when we move to the new version?

Comment: There are two Oracle drivers that I am aware of: Attunity and the other one (maybe a generic MS driver?) Attunity is the high performance one that requires the Enterprise Edition licensed. It sounds like perhaps the driver that the 2015 package(s) use is not installed, not configured or the connection manager itself needs to be updated to use the v2019 drivers. Oh and of course there's always configuration of tnsname.ora I don't Oracle so I can't be more specific than that

Comment: @billinkc I had been using Attunity in 2015 version. But the same doesnt work with the 2019 version. Is the connector paid now? I saw on their website that  its replaced with the generic MS driver. Everything was working fine before with the old Visual Studio version but stopped with the new version. The tnsnames.ora is updated correctly otherwise it wouldnt have worked with the old version as well.